# Calculate x/y point that 2 moving balls will collide

Tags: math, language-agnostic, collision-detection, physics

I'm trying to make what is (essentially) a simple pool game, and would like to be able to predict where a shot will go once it hits another ball.

The first part is, I believe, to calculate if the cueball will hit anything, and if it does, where it collides. I can work out collision points for a line and a ball, but not 2 balls.

So given the x/y positions and velocities of 2 balls, how do I calculate the point at which they collide?

(PS: Im aware I can do this by calculating the distance between the two balls every step along the way, but I was hoping for something a little more elegant and optimal.)

Example of setup: trying to calculate the red dot

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6202117/circle.PNG

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some things to take note of:

- When two balls, each of radius `r` collide their centers are `2r` apart.
- Your first ball can be assumed to travel in a straight line (well, first approximation, but start with this), and you can find the angle, `alpha` between this path and the direction from the first ball to the second.
- You know the center of the stationary ball, no?

Now you have some geometry to do.

Do this construction:

1. Mark the current center of the first (moving) ball as point `A`.
2. Mark the center of the stationary ball as point `B`.
3. Construct line segment `AB`.
4. Construct the ray, `R`, from `A` in the direction of movement.
5. Construct a circle of radius `2r` around `B`.
6. Drop a segment from `B` perpendicular to `R` call the point of intersection `C`.
7. You know the distance `AB` and you can find the angle `alpha` between `AB` and `R`, with the Law of Sines find the length of `BC`.
8. From that length determine if there are 0, 1 or 2 solutions. If there are 0 or 1 you are done.
9. Construct point `D` where the circle meets `R` closer to A, and use the Law of Sines again to find the distance AD.
10. The point of collision is the midpoint of `BD`

and now you know everything.

Constructing efficient code from this is left as an exercise.

---

BTW-- This construction won't work if both balls are moving, but you can transform into a frame where one is stationary, solve it that way, then transform back. Just be sure to check that the solution is in the allowed area *after* the reverse transformation...

/ Physicists can't **not** make comments like this. I tried to resist. I *really* did.

Comment: Gah, Im an idiot. Ive had several people explain this to me previously, its only now that I get it. For some reason I was convinced doing 2r would cause collisions to be wonky.

Appreciate the help, I should be able to work this out from here.

Comment: After you've done this kind of thing a few times you'll reach for a pad or a whiteboard automatically. That's point at which you're are forever lost to the world of men...

Comment: Is it bad that this answer made me feel like I was in high school geometry again... and kind of liked it?

Comment: Just checked your profile, dmckee.  Neutrinos - nice work.  Sounds like it's starting pay off after many years.  I really liked this answer and look forward to more from you.

Answer (score 12):

Drawing of @dmckee's answer

[image]

**Edit**

Just in response to @ArtB necromancer's answer, the solutions for point D in the above graph could be written:

```
1/2 {(Ax+Bx+2 d Dx Cos[alpha]- Dx Cos[2 alpha]+ 2 Dy (Cos[alpha]-d) Sin[alpha]), 
     (Ay+By+2 d Dy Cos[alpha]- Dy Cos[2 alpha]- 2 Dx (Cos[alpha]-d) Sin[alpha])
     }
```

Where

```
Dx = Ax - Bx 
Dy = Ay - By
```

And

```
d = Sqrt[4 r^2 - (Dx^2 + Dy^2) Sin[alpha]^2]/Sqrt[Dx^2 + Dy^2]
```

HTH!

Answer (score 1):

I was looking at @dmckee's solution and it took me quite a lot of work to work through it. The following is my notes for those perhaps looking for a more practical answer, it is taken directly
from his post so the credit goes to him/her, but any mistakes are mine. I usual a Pascal-like assigment operator (ie `:=`) to distinguish between showing my work and the actual necessary code.
I'm using the standard `Y = mX +b` format and a quasi-oop notation. I do use BC for both the segment and the resulting line. That said, this should 'almost' be copy'n'paste-able Python code 
(remove ";", replace "sqrt" and "sqr" with proper versions, etc).

1. A.x and A.y are the x & y positions, A.r is A's radius, and A.v is the velocity with A.v.x being the x component of it and A.v.y being the y component of it.
2. B is the same but without the velocity (or more accurately, subtract the velocities of B from A so B is relatively speaking stationary).
3. `AB.m := (b.y - a.y) / (b.x - a.x);` `AB.b := A.y - AB.m * A.x;`
4. `R.m := A.v.y / A.v.x;` `R.b := A.y - R.m * A.x;`
5. *not necessary*
6. `BC.m := -A.v.x/A.v.y;` which is the standard equation for perpendicular slope, `BC.b := B.y - BC.m * B.x;` Now `C` is where `AB` meets `BC` so we know that they are equal so lets equate `C.y` so `C.y == AB.m * C.x + AB.b == BC.m * C.x + BC.b;` so `C.x := (AB.m - BC.M) / (BC.b - AB.b);` then just plug in `C.x` to get `C.y := AB.m * C.x + AB.b;`
7. You can ignore the sine law since we have AB and BC so we can just use the Pythagorean theorem to get the length of `BC`, `BC.l := sqrt( sqr(B.x-C.x) + sqr(B.y-C.y) );`
8. If `BC.l > A.r + B.r`, there are zero solutions, and these circles do not touch since `C` is `A`'s path`s perigee with respect to`B`. If`BC.l == A.r + B.r`, there is only one solution, and`C == D`. Otherwise, if`BC.l < A.r + B.r`then there
   are two solutions. You can think of this as such, if there are zero solutions the bullet missed, if there is one the bullet grazed, and if there are two then there is both an entry and exit wound. The one closer to`A` is the one we want.
9. 1. Now, the math gets ugly so I'll show my work just in case I do something wrong.
   2. `D` is a point on `AC` that is `A.r + B.r` (aka `2r`) away from B so: 
      `sqrt( sqr(D.x - B.x) + sqr(D.y - B.y) ) == 2r`
   3. Therefore `sqr(D.x - B.x) + sqr(D.y - B.y) == 4*r*r`. Now 2 variables (ie `D.x` and `D.y`) with one equation is trouble, but we also know that `D` is 
      on the line `AC` so `D.y == AC.m*D.x + AC.b`.
   4. We can substitute for `D.y` giving `sqr(D.x - B.x) + sqr(AC.m*C.x + AC.b - B.y) == 4*r*r`.
   5. This expands into the lovely: `sqr(D.x) + 2*D.x - sqr(B.x) + sqr(AC.m*D.x) + 2*AC.b*D.x - 2*AC.m*D.x*B.y + sqr(AC.b) - 2*AC.b*B.y + sqr(B.y)  == 4*r*r` (**this** is the part where I mostly likely made a mistake *if* I did at all).
   6. These terms we can collect (remember, at this point only `D.x` is unknown; the rest we can treat as if they were constants) to get 
      `sqr(D.x) + 2*D.x - sqr(B.x) + sqr(AC.m*D.x) + 2*AC.b*D.x - 2*AC.m*D.x*B.y + sqr(AC.b) - 2*AC.b*B.y + sqr(B.y)  == 4*r*r`
   7. Rewritten into the neater 
      `(sqr(D.x) + sqr(AC.m*D.x))  +  ( 2*D.x + 2*AC.b*D.x - 2*AC.m*B.y*D.x )  +  ( - sqr(B.x) + sqr(AC.b) - 2*AC.b*B.y + sqr(B.y) ) == 4*r*r` which can be refactored to
      `(1 + sqr(AC.m)) * sqr(D.x) +  2*( 1 + AC.b - AC.m*B.y ) * D.x + ( sqr(B.y) - sqr(B.x) + sqr(AC.b) - 2*AC.b*B.y  - 4*r*r ) == 0`
   8. This now fits nicely into the quadratic formula (ie `x == (-bb +- sqrt( sqr(bb) - 4*aa*cc ) / 2*aa`) (using `aa` to avoid confusion with earlier variables), with `aa := 1 + sqr(AC.m);`, `bb := 2*( 1 + AC.b - AC.m*B.y );`, and `cc := sqr(B.y) - sqr(B.x) + sqr(AC.b) - 2*AC.b*B.y  - sqr(A.r+B.r);`.
   9. Now we might get two solution so lets save the parts using `-bb/2aa +- sqrt(sqr(bb)-4*aa*cc)/2*aa`: `first_term := -bb/(2*a);` and `second_term := sqrt(sqr(bb)-4*aa*cc)/2*aa;`.
   10. First solution `D1.x = first_term + second_term;` with `D1.y = AC.m * D1.x + AC.b`, and a second solution `D2.x = first_term + second_term;` with `D2.y = AC.m * D2.x + AC.b`.
   11. Find the distances to `A`: `D1.l := sqrt( sqr(D1.x-A.x) + sqr(D1.y-A.y) );` and `D2.l = sqrt( sqr(D2.x-A.x) + sqr(D2.y-A.y) );` (actually it is more efficient to skip both square roots, but it makes no difference).
   12. The closer one is one you want `D := D1 if D1.l < D2. l else D2;`.
10. 1. The midpoint of `DB`, lets call it E, is the collision (I don't know how this generalises if the radii aren't equal).
    2. So constuct the line `DB.m := (B.y-D.y)/(B.x-D.x);` and `DB.b = B.y - DB.m*B.x;`.
    3. We don't need the length to determine the length since it should be `BD.l == A.r + B.r`, so `sqrt( sqr(E.x-B.x) + sqr(E.y-B.y) ) == B.r`.
    4. Again, we can substitute for `E` because we know it's on `BD` so `E.y == BD.m * E.x + BD.b`, getting `sqrt( sqr(E.x-B.x) + sqr(BD.m * E.x + BD.b-B.y) ) == B.r`.
    5. Expanding into `sqr(E.x) - 2*E.x*B.x + sqr(B.x) + sqr(BD.m)*sqr(E.x) + 2*BD.m*E.x*BD.b - 2*BD.m*B.y + sqr(B.y) - 2*BD.b*B.y + sqr(B.y) == sqr(B.r)`
    6. Which collects into

    `sqr(E.x) + sqr(BD.m)*sqr(E.x) + 2*BD.m*E.x*BD.b - 2*E.x*B.x + sqr(B.x) - 2*BD.m*B.y + sqr(B.y) - 2*BD.b*B.y + sqr(B.y) == sqr(B.r)`
    `(1 + sqr(BD.m)) * sqr(E.x)  +  2*(BD.m*BD.b - B.x) * E.x  + sqr(B.x)  +  sqr(B.y) - 2*BD.m*B.y + sqr(B.y) - 2*BD.b*B.y + sqr(B.y) - sqr(B.r) == 0`
    `aa := (1 + sqr(BD.m)); bb := 2*(BD.m*BD.b - B.x); cc := sqr(B.y) - 2*BD.m*B.y + sqr(B.y) - 2*BD.b*B.y + sqr(B.y) - sqr(B.r);`, quadratic formula, and then get your two points and choose the one closer to B.

I wish I was just whoring for karma or the necromancer badge, but I really needed to work this out and figured I'd share. Ugh, I think I need to lay down now.

Comment: Now that's just embarassing. Well, at least I tried. Thank for a simpler alternative to my mess.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember to start your comments with @Username, so your party gets notified. I just came back here cross-checking my answer!

Comment: Depending on your application, you may not need to know where every point in the construction is. You may also find this easier if you write the math out in vector terms: I *always* get lost if I try to write it all in components early on.